# pipenv is not recognized on powershell

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I made sure `pipenv` was installed in the following path `C:\Users\Owner> pip install pipenv`

Then got the following response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\
ackages (from pipenv) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pac
(from pipenv) (20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-pack
from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pi
(16.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pipen
20.4.5.1)
```

After that, I tried to set it up in a specific directory. And, then I got the following message.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner\desktop\Python\Pyprojects> pipenv install
The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
ling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ pipenv <<<<  install
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Before, it kept saying that I didn't have the wheel set up. So, I installed that. But, now I get the above mentioned error messages. How can I resolve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you set the `Pipenv Path` correctly in the settings？Just like this: `C:\Python\Python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe`

Answer (score 12):

Seems you don't have pipenv in your PATH environment variable.

You should check for your python install location e.g. I have it installed at C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

Include "python_install_location\Scripts" in your PATH environment variable. e.g.

C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\

To set your environment variable:

1. Open Control Panel\System and Security\System from your file
   explorer.
2. Advanced System Settings
3. Environment Variables...
4. Select Path and Edit
5. Add a new row to include above path.

Scripts folder must have an entry like

[image: pipenv script]

To verify run pipenv --version

[image]

Comment: I did that and get the same results. I just added Scripts\ to a new path or should I add more? Once I get to powershell, and the correct directory, what should I type to see if pipenv works?

Comment: Do I do that for system variables or for owner? I've tried both. When I try to add the path for the scripts, it replaces my previous path for python. It won't let me add multiple paths.

Comment: You may add multiple path separated by semi-colon(;)

Comment: Run pipenv --version to check if it's working. You may check the screenshot attached in answer.

Comment: See the note under https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv which confirms the folder containing pipenv may need to be added to the path

Answer (score 4):

I simply restarted my computer after finding the pipenv.py file in the correct directory (/Scripts) and adding it to the environment variable path, and now pipenv works wonderfully on my Windows PC! Restarting will allow your computer to update your environment variables that you adjusted in the control panel.

Answer (score 3):

Something I had an issue with as well and my script folder was in the PATH variables list. I found uninstalling virtualenv -
`pip uninstall virtualenv`

Then removing pipenv as well
`pip uninstall pipenv`

then reinstalling pipenv
`pip install pipenv`

Solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you type in "pip install pipenv" in your terminal, the terminal will tell you the location of your pipenv file; it is usually in the first line. Make sure to follow that location, then copy it and add to PATH environment.

I found pipenv under this location : C:\Users"UserName"\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

The default `Scripts` installation location is not added to the path by default. A more generic addition you can make is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts`. Change the Python version to what you currently use as a default Python version in your path.